# Database synchronization - XML or JSON

Tags: xml, database, json

I write app for android which will be synchronize databases located on android device with external database. In short Android generate some data and store it in own database. From time to time Android send this data through internet to HTTP server. I'm wondering, what will be better to send this data XML or JSON? I know that JSON is much more lighter than XML but do XML any advantage on JSON? What is better to synchronize databases?

Comment: If you have the tools to parse both of them, it really comes down to preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very large data sets XML will be slightly heavier because it needs opening and closing tags. There is also the question of how big the data between tags is. If you have large amount of data in between opening and closing tags, then this "softens" the effect. If you are not working with a ton of data, then I would just use whichever has better native library support for both client and server. For small to medium datasets, I do not think the difference will be very noticeable.

Answer (score 2):

I would say json.... since json is lighter and if what you are looking for is simply passing data, json is the faster, simpler way. I work with both json and xml for a while now and I did not yet found any reason to prefer xml over json, except maybe that XML "looks" better...

Anyway, if you are using existing parsing and encoding tools (e.g. JAXB), the transition from json to xml should take you 2-3 lines of code, sio you can also switch one for another...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend JSON as it is much more lightweight than XML, and in my opinion the easier format to deal with. Either will accomplish the job. Other things to consider are the service you're using on the HTTP Server to intercept the data. Are you writing your own? Using a preexisting one that may work better with one format over the other?

Also is there a reason for not connecting directly to the remote database and updating it that way? I know constantly doing that could slow down the app and create massive data usage, but if you only do it sparingly like you're planning on doing it shouldn't be that big of an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated whether this is a single user or multi-user application.... Distributed data synchronization is not a simple problem to solve.

If this is a single user solution, I would investigate whether your database supports replication. If your dataset is small I would also consider simply posting the database dumpfile. Both solutions avoid the performance overhead of serializing data into and out of XML/JSON. Also avoids database type support nastiness.

Finally, for a "left field" solution why not consider storing your data in [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/)? Client server replication built-in.

- [Android-Couchdb](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase-SourceBuild)
- There is a new javascript client called [pouchdb](http://pouchdb.com/), which is worth evaluating.